# GuzzleHttp Laravel - Could not resolve host: myapplication.dev

Tags: laravel, virtualhost, hosts, guzzle

I'm developing and application on forge.laravel.com and I need to use GuzzleHttp.

The problem is that I haven't registered the domain myapplication.dev yet.

When I navigate on website from client I solved it putting this in my windows hosts file:

```
myapplication.dev X.XX.XX.XXX
```

but obliviously this doesn't work for requests from server.

This is how I call GuzzleHttp:

```
$client = new Client([
          'base_uri' => request()->getSchemeAndhttpHost(),
          'headers' => request()->header()
      ]);
      $name = $client->get('/example.getName?id=1')->getBody()->getContents();
```

Can I force to redirect myapplication.dev to my application with Forge?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure , you can setup the ip address of your server in the config of nginx.

```
listen 80;
server_name THE_IP;
root /var/www/html;  #the location of your root dir...
```

https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx/

Take a look at server blocks.

then in your guzzle client point to an ip instead of a domain.

Comment: I use Forge.lavavel.com, when I try to change NGINX config I get this error: conflicting server name "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Comment: It is not what you're looking for, but may be it helps: another different approach is to implement a mock-handler. See http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html#mock-handler